# How to load external RCL components bundled css files?

Tags: c#, winforms, blazor

I am building a Hybrid Blazor app using WinForms and have a number of RCL files which are not referenced as part of the main project. They are loaded dynamically and instantiated using DynamicComponent when specific buttons are clicked.

The assemblies are loaded with `Assembly dll = Assembly.LoadFrom(module);`

The types are loaded with `IRazorModule? razorApp = (IRazorModule?)Activator.CreateInstance(type);` and passed in to DynamicComponent.

How can I dynamically load/link the bundled css file when the button is clicked? The css bundle does not appear to be in the _content folder when inspecting via dev tools. How can it be loaded on the fly?

Comment: _"I am building a Hybrid Blazor app using WinForms"_ - Please explain how you plan to make `System.Windows.Forms` work in a WASM environment (or do you mean, you're just building a WinForms host for a `WebView` which un-turn hosts Blazor?)... also, _something something turtles all the way down_

Comment: Yes that is correct, I have a WinForms application and a BlazorWebView

Comment: @Dai It's an interesting alternative to self-hosting that's using a dedicated WebView. You can interact with `.razor` pages from a Form and the other way around. E.g., in an element's `@onclick="OnClick"` you can simply write `@code { private void OnClick() => new SomeForm().Show(); }`. So you can have a mix of WinForms Controls and HTML elements that interact with each other. It's not bad

Comment: Are your libraries using CSS isolation? -- Note that I'm not sure how this work when the type is loaded like that. The scoped CSS should be determined at compile-time (IIRC)

Comment: Yes I am using CSS isolation. If the RCL is referenced from the WinForms project then the css bundle is created and made available in the virtual _content folder. I can then inject this on click into the HTML using JavaScript, but these RCL files cannot be referenced from the main project. They work like plugins.

Comment: Why _"RCL files which are not referenced as part of the main project"_ ? That is your main problem and I don't see the advantage.